# gem5: X86 KVM full system support for readfile pseudo instruction

Tags: gem5

I have been trying to get a gem5 full system simulation working using X86-KVM. It manages to boot successfully, however when I try to pass a script to be executed after booting it always ends in this error:

```
panic: could not seek: Invalid argument
```

Also, these are some messages I get when I enable the PseudoInst debug flag:

```
40505125609053: global: PseudoInst::pseudoInst(80, 0)
40505125609053: global: PseudoInst::readfile(0x7fffb4591f10, 0x40000, 0xffffffff80002000)
```

I have read in another [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg22353.html) that most instructions should be working except for readfile which needed a patch.

Do you know if the problem has been fixed since then or if such a patch exists? I have been looking around but couldn't find one.

Comment: Did you search on gerrit around that time for the patch he mentioned? Or do a `git log --grep`? Also maybe this one is not hard to deduce from GDB + soruces, m5op activation is a shallow subject. Also send an email to the mailing list and ask people from that thread.

Comment: I couldn't find a patch, but I will try the mailing list. Thanks, Ciro!

Comment: I found this patch which looks promising so far: https://github.com/darchr/gem5/commit/d8041a088fab8ef11a8783a55d25e184265940b0

Comment: great, don't forget to answer your own question if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this patch which looks promising so far:
https://github.com/darchr/gem5/commit/d8041a088fab8ef11a8783a55d25e184265940b0